# How to enable/disable many controls including push buttons simultaneously in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a GUI by using `QtDesigner` and `PyQt5`. There are 60 push buttons and I want to disable/enable 50 of them by pushing 61th push button. How it can be achieved?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have done several Windows Form (C#) projects and am newbie in `PyQt` world.
In windows form and using C# I change the property of a specific type of control for example push buttons like this: `ButtonsList = GetAccessToAllButtons(this).OfType<Button>().ToList();`. Then run a `foreach` loop  to change the desired property. I don't know what the correspond methods are in `PyQt`.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to add the buttons you want to enable/disable to a button group. In QtDesigner this can be done by selecting the buttons, right-clicking on the selection and choosing "Assign to button group" in the popup menu. You can then iterate over `buttongroup.buttons()` to enable/disable them.